# Would using the advanced built-in functions on a CAS calculator be cheating?

Tags: ethics, cheating

On a test on a course that isn't math, but uses it, such as physics or engineering, would using a CAS to reduce the handiwork I have to do be considered cheating? 
For example, what if I used the equation solver to solve equations, rather than do it by hand? Or what if I let the calculator do integrals and differentiations for me?

This is assuming the professor never said anything about what kind of calculators were allowed, nor about what we do with them. (Using them as a cheat sheet would definitely be cheating, but this is not what I am asking about.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just ask your professor?

Comment: These days, there is a near continuum from calculators that can only do a very limited set of functions to smart phones. The exam will have a boundary on what the professor intends to permit, and if it is not clear whether a given device is permitted, ask.

Answer (score 0):

In our university exams: The question papers, as well as the exam regulation sheets, mention that "Programmable Calculators are NOT allowed."

The CAS calculator that you are talking about is not programmable (to the best of my knowledge). So, you are free to use equation solvers, integration solves, etc.

This will not be considered cheating (at least at my university).

However, you must enquire about this with your instruction division of the university or the course head. In fact, you should show her a demo of the things that you can do with the calculator.

Comment: Why would you assume it is not programmable? Most calculators I know of, which have the functions mentioned, are programmable.

Comment: OP here. My calculator is programmable, which wouldn't be allowed at your university. However, in my case, there is no university-wide ban on certain calculators.